# Kакие знаки препинания поставить в выражении?

Tags: пунктуация

Kакие знаки препинания поставить в выражении: "Прошу сегодня ко мне обращаться Ваше Высочество Ирина Владимировна"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

***Обращайтесь ко мне "мой господин" или "повелитель",*** говорите со мной в третьем лице, в моём присутствии всегда принимайте почтительный вид.
[**Жюльетта**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=_CbcxfCzpbQC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD&source=bl&ots=sHI4WZ1UPd&sig=h8jJCSHPzKD09jwVYtLlJYMNE7I&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji9qvMlNnTAhWGWywKHaUpDS0Q6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD&f=false)

*Не сомневаюсь, что мне еще доведется **величать его «ваше превосходительство»** и вставать, когда он входит в комнату.*
[**У.С.Моэм, Узорный покров**](https://studyenglishwords.com/book/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/271?page=82)

*К тому же, когда я представилась, **он обратился ко мне "ваша светлость"**, а не **"миледи"** , что более распространено, он слегка поклонился и поцеловал мне руку.*
***Обращайся ко мне "Ваша Милость"***, кузен!
*Вы должны **ко мне обращаться "Ваше Королевское Высочество".***
[**русский-английский, переводы**](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5+%22%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0)

В Вашем примере правильно так:
***Прошу сегодня ко мне обращаться "Ваше Высочество, Ирина Владимировна".***

*— Они там все в ложе! Ваше Высочество, Владимир Александрович, вы-то мне и нужны! Мы же с вами тогда ночью не договорили! Не помните что ли? Ну, мы вам еще все стекла в карете перебили? Не помните?!*
[**Три короба правды**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=41528&p=83)

Answer (score 0):

Прошу сегодня ко мне обращаться **"Ваше Высочество Ирина Владимировна".**

Сравнить:  Родари Джанни. Принц-пломбир.

И обращайтесь ко мне отныне **"ваше высочество"**. - Разумеется, ваше высочество, разумеется.